# possible ways to implement push notification in firebase as parse

Tags: backend, mbaas

i am switching my app from `parse` to `firebase` (have to select `firebase` after checking out  dozens of `mbaas`  ) but as we all know `firebase` didn't handle  `push notification` so what ways we have to implement `push notification` ,my  app is based on `android` and `iOS` platforms ?

Comment: It is interesting, why you have chosen firebase, when you knew it does not handle one of your requirements?

Comment: hey @Andrew thanks for replying ,  because it suits my other requirements very well but not the notification one , well i found a way but it requires some knowledge about server side code and node.js and i know nothing about this two things (or maybe they are a single thing ) well i followed this tutorial https://batch.com/parse-replacement-with-firebase and it worked but for making it automatic i have to do this:   write your own server-side code to 1. detect Firebase db changes 2. call the Batch API.

Answer (score 2):

You can now integrate Batch with Firebase to get push notifications.

https://batch.com/parse-replacement-with-firebase

https://batch.com/

Comment: thank man , i already  know about (batch + firebase integration ) but for others don't so maybe your answer will help anybody with same requirement